# Why is my 2012 Impala still shaking after I got a tune up?

Tags: traction-control, service-manual, stability, tune-up

My 2012 Chevy Impala was doing just fine until two weeks ago.  I auto started my car, while walking up it shut off on its own.  I got in the car and the check engine light came on as well messages for service Stabilitrack and Service Traction (something, I can quite remember). When I am at a complete stop the car stutters with vibration.  I got the ignition coil in Cylinder 1 as well as the spark plugs for cylunders 1-6 changed.  The car now switches gears at the proper time but there is still a stutter, When the spark plug is removed from cylinder 1 the car runs fine without the stutter. What could this be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. There seems to be more than one problem going on. Get the codes read and update your questions with what you find. That will give us a starting point in helping you figure out what is going on. Otherwise, all you will get are guesses.

Comment: What do you mean "the spark plug is removed from cylinder 1 the car runs fine without the stutter"? You're saying with a spark plug completely out of the engine, engine running on 5 cylinders, it runs fine? Not seeing how this can be. Can you please explain?

Comment: I took it to a mechanic and he is now sayin it is a fuel injector problem, The stutter is still there . Do you have an idea on how much this could run me?